# how do I get a count of matches across multiple tables joining by id?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I 'score' results using order by, if possible, by number of matches between a given user and every other user in a table.

Basically, I have a given 'userid' of '1' and I need to check all of this users 'interests' against of users interests and order by the number of like matches between users.

Say userid '1' has 4 interests in common with userid '4', but only 3 interests in common with userid '2', it would return 4 first, then 2, then everyone else with less overall interest matches.

I have tried about 10 different queries to no avail, not even one that was close, which is why I didn't post any of the attempts here.

```
CREATE TABLE `interests` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `interest` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term1';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term3';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term4';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term1';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term8';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term4';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term9';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term3';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term7';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term1';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term3';
INSERT INTO `interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term4';
```

The proper result set should look like:

```
-------
userid
-------
4
2
3
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `SELF JOIN`:

```
SELECT i2.userid
FROM interests i1
INNER JOIN interests i2
  ON i2.userid <> i1.userid
  AND i2.interest = i1.interest
WHERE i1.userid = 1
GROUP BY i2.userid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d247/5/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Felix, after just a slight modification, this solution turned out to be far faster than the others presented.

Comment: Felix, how would you go about refining this just a bit, to increase speed, by making it first require a match for `country` = '1' in a different table named `users`. Then going thru the interest matches as it does now?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to get a list of all users and shares and counts and then select and order the ones you want from that sub-query.  It makes the logic clear:

```
SELECT userid, otherid, sameCount
FROM (
  SELECT base.userid, other.userid as otherid, count(*) sameCount
  FROM interests base
  JOIN interests other ON base.interest = other.interest and base.userid != other.userid
  GROUP BY base.userid, other.userid
) sub
WHERE userid = 1
ORDER BY sameCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it

```
select i.userid, count(i2.userid) countInterests
from interests i
inner join interests i2 on i.interest = i2.interest and i.Id <> i2.id
group by i.userid, i2.userid
order by userid, count(i2.userid) desc
```